# Error inserting data into 2 tables in mySQL with resultSet.update()

Tags: mysql, jdbc, resultset

I am geeting this error when inserting data into the fileds of one table, then changing the resultSet SQL statement to another table, and inserting into fields of table 2:

> SEVERE: null com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable: Result Set not
>   updatable.This result set must come from a statement that was created
>   with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must
>   select only one table, can not use functions and must select all
>   primary keys from that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification,
>   section 5.6 for more details.

The resultSet statement is set to updatable:

```
statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
```

The resultSet stament for Table 1 and the table:

```
resultSet =  (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery(SELECT * FROM employees);

+----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+
| socialSecurityNumber | firstName | lastName | birthday   | employeeType               | departmentName |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+
| 111-11-1111          | John      | Smith    | 1945-01-02 | salariedEmployee           | R&D            |
| 222-22-2222          | Sue       | Jones    | 1961-02-03 | commissionEmployee         | SALES          |
| 234435               | ciaran    | mooney   | 2013-11-28 | commissionEmployee         | Sales          |
| 333-33-3333          | Bob       | Lowis    | 1958-10-05 | basePlusCommissionEmployee | SALES          |
| 444-44-4444          | Karen     | Price    | 1972-05-25 | hourlyEmployee             | HR             |
+----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------+
| socialSecurityNumber | grossSales | commissionRate | bonus |
+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------+
| 222-22-2222          |      10100 |           0.05 |     0 |
| 222-22-2222          |   12234445 |            0.6 |   300 |
+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```java
//using a object of class employee to update Table employees via resultSet
//manipulate the data in the resultSet, then  upadteRow to save changes on DataBase
        resultSet.moveToInsertRow();//insert a into a empty row
        resultSet.updateString("socialSecurityNumber", addEmployee.getSocialSecurityNumber());
        resultSet.updateString("firstName", addEmployee.getFirstName());
        resultSet.updateString("lastName", addEmployee.getLastName());
        resultSet.updateString("departmentName", addEmployee.getDepartment());
        resultSet.updateDate("birthday", new java.sql.Date(addEmployee.getDOB().getTime()));
        resultSet.updateString("employeeType", "commissionEmployee");
        resultSet.updateString("departmentName", addEmployee.getDepartment());


        //EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
        //new resultSet for commsionRate employee
        statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
        resultSet = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM commissionEmployees");
        resultSet.updateString("socialSecurityNumber", addEmployee.getSocialSecurityNumber());
        resultSet.updateInt("grossSales", (int)addEmployee.getGrossSales());

        resultSet.updateDouble("commissionRate", addEmployee.getCommissionRate());
        resultSet.updateDouble("bonus", 0);

        //uopdate the database*/
        resultSet.insertRow();

        //return cursor to orginal position
        resultSet.beforeFirst();
```

The primary key is the SocialSecurityNumber field present in both tables.
The exception is thrown when i attempt to change the resultSet to table 2 as highlighted above..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Shot in the dark, perhaps: have you tried closing the first resultSet, before you open the second?

Comment: yep, closed and created new resultSet of the table 2(commissionEmployee):                                  resultSet.close();
statement = (Statement)connection.createStatement(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
resultSet = (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM commissionEmployees");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling [`createStatement(int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28int,%20int%29) with the wrong order of arguments:

> **Parameters:**
>      `resultSetType` - a result set type; one of `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, or `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`
>      `resultSetConcurrency` - a concurrency type; one of `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` or `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`

So you should call it as:

```
createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Some combinations of type and concurrency might not necessarily be supported. I don't know what applies to the MySQL driver. A driver might downgrade (JDBC 4.1 specification section 15.1.2):

> If the driver cannot return a `ResultSet` object at the requested type and concurrency, it determines the appropriate type before determining the concurrency

Comment: The devil is in the detail....i changed the order of arguments suggested & worked fine, thanks all for your input